# How to create an Interface that extends two other Interfaces to define type in java

Tags: java, oop, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have two interfaces `Inquiry` and `Validatable`
and I also have two classes `ErrorReport` and `FunctionQuery` implements `Inquiry` and `Validatable` both.

What is the best choice when I have a logic that uses a combination of two interfaces' operation?
I know that I can separate it into two logic using `Inquiry` and `Validatable`, but the logic is combined so If I separate it, it makes other duplication.

I tried like below, but, I realized this hierarchy is not appropriate because `Validatable` is not a generalization of `Inquiry` in my application.

### approach at first

```
public interface Inquiry extends Validatable {
  ...
}
```

and classes like this.

```
public class ErrorReport implements Inquiry{
  ...
}
```

```
public class FunctionQuery implements Inquiry {
  ...
}
```

### new approach

So I create an interface like below.

```
public interface ValidatableInquiry extends Inquiry,Validatable{
  ...
}
```

and classes

```
public class ErrorReport implements ValidatableInquiry {
  ...
}
```

```
public class FunctionQuery implements ValidatableInquiry {
  ...
}
```

I think the new approach is better than the first, but I can't be assured.
Is it the right approach? and Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a certain degree, this is opinionated. Both solutions "work" for a smaller project of limited life time.

But then it is very clear that the first solution carries one significant constraint: it introduces coupling between `Inquiry` and `Validatable`.

Thus the answer is: if you are **really** sure about your "model", and the abstractions that you want to create ... in the sense of: *yes, absolutely, any `Inquiry` will always be a `Validatable`, too*, then that solution is okay. Because your code matches your mental model, and you are sure about the validity of your mental model.

But if there is the *slightest* doubt that these two interface are actually **independent** of each other, then you should pick the 2nd approach. Because that approach says: the two interfaces are independent, and classes that need both functionalities can extend from that *joining* interface that brings the functionalities together.